# Running total SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cumulative-sum, sql-cte

So far, I have the following SQL Server 2005 query:

```
WITH D AS (
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2020.11.01', 102) AS d_y_m, CAST('2020-11-01' AS DATETIME) AS dt
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, 1, z.dt), 102) AS d_y_m, DATEADD(dd, 1, z.dt)
FROM D AS z
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, z.dt) <= '2020-11-30')
SELECT x.d_y_m, ISNULL(SUM(y.Total), 0) AS [Invoiced], ISNULL(SUM(FEI.Total), 0) AS [Paid] FROM D x
LEFT JOIN Invoices y ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, y.InvoiceDate, 102) = x.d_y_m
LEFT JOIN Payments AS FEI ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, FEI.PaymentDate, 102) = x.d_y_m
GROUP BY x.d_y_m
ORDER BY x.d_y_m OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

How do I add another column (RunningTotal) to the query which sums up the (Invoiced-Paid) result from the previous day to the one for today

Example:

```
d_y_m | Invoiced | Paid | RunningTotal

2020.11.01 | 24 | 5 | 19

2020.11.02 | 45 | 2 | 62

2020.11.03 | 10 | 20 | 52

2020.11.04 | 5 | 0 | 57

2020.11.05 | 0 | 10 | 47
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple remarks on your current solution:

- Do not use "random" table aliases. `D` for "dates" makes sense. `y` for "Invoices" does not. `d_y_m` does not match your date format either. Keep the table and column aliases meaningful.
- Do not drag the date conversion through your entire solution. Work with date values as `date` types and convert the values *once* in the final `select`.
- Do not group the sums of the invoiced and paid amounts in one query. If you have multiple invoices or payments on a single day, then the sums will be incorrect! See the "Extra" section at the bottom for an explanation.
- Make it easy for us to help you. Next time, please provide sample data that we can copy-paste instead of having to invent our own.
- SQL Server 2005 is [officially unsupported](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/13/are-you-still-running-sql-server-2005-now-is-the-time-to-upgrade-to-a-modern-data-platform/) as of April 12, 2016. Time to look for a new version!

**Sample data**

```
create table Invoices
(
  InvoiceDate date,
  Total money
);

insert into Invoices (InvoiceDate, Total) values
('2020-11-01', 20),
('2020-11-01',  4),
('2020-11-02', 40),
('2020-11-02',  5),
('2020-11-03', 10),
('2020-11-04',  3),
('2020-11-04',  2);

create table Payments
(
  PaymentDate date,
  Total money
);

insert into Payments (PaymentDate, Total) values
('2020-11-01',  5),
('2020-11-02',  2),
('2020-11-03', 10),
('2020-11-03', 10),
('2020-11-05', 10);
```

**Solution**

```
with DateRange as
(
  select convert(date, '2020-11-01') as DateValue
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, dr.DateValue)
  from DateRange dr
  where dr.DateValue < '2020-11-30'
),
InvoicedTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(i.Total), 0) as Invoiced
  from DateRange dr
  left join Invoices i
    on i.InvoiceDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
),
PaidTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(p.Total), 0) as Paid
  from DateRange dr
  left join Payments p
    on p.PaymentDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
)
select convert(varchar(10), dr.DateValue, 102) as [YYYY.MM.DD],
       it.Invoiced as [Invoiced],
       sum(it.Invoiced) over(order by it.DateValue
                             rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as [CumInvoiced],
       pt.Paid as [Paid],
       sum(pt.Paid) over(order by pt.DateValue
                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as [CumPaid],
       sum(it.Invoiced) over(order by it.DateValue
                             rows between unbounded preceding and current row) -
       sum(pt.Paid) over(order by pt.DateValue
                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as [RunningTotal]
from DateRange dr
join InvoicedTotal it
  on it.DateValue = dr.DateValue
join PaidTotal pt
  on pt.DateValue = dr.DateValue
order by dr.DateValue;
```

**Result**

Only listing the first 10 of the 30 rows for November.

```
YYYY.MM.DD Invoiced CumInvoiced Paid    CumPaid RunningTotal
---------- -------- ----------- ------- ------- ------------
2020.11.01  24.0000     24.0000  5.0000  5.0000      19.0000
2020.11.02  45.0000     69.0000  2.0000  7.0000      62.0000
2020.11.03  10.0000     79.0000 20.0000 27.0000      52.0000
2020.11.04   5.0000     84.0000  0.0000 27.0000      57.0000
2020.11.05   0.0000     84.0000 10.0000 37.0000      47.0000
2020.11.06   0.0000     84.0000  0.0000 37.0000      47.0000
2020.11.07   0.0000     84.0000  0.0000 37.0000      47.0000
2020.11.08   0.0000     84.0000  0.0000 37.0000      47.0000
2020.11.09   0.0000     84.0000  0.0000 37.0000      47.0000
2020.11.10   0.0000     84.0000  0.0000 37.0000      47.0000
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=932121d21fcb616bcf0ade63e8c3e025) to see it in action.

---

**Extra**: why *not* to count both totals in one query.

Using the same sample data you can run this query to zoom in a particular date, here: `2020-11-01`. On this date the sample data has 2 invoices and 1 payment.

```
with DateRange as
(
  select '2020-11-01' as DateValue -- filtering data to explain
)
select dr.DateValue,
       isnull(sum(i.Total), 0) as Invoiced,
       isnull(sum(p.Total), 0) as Paid
from DateRange dr
left join Invoices i
  on i.InvoiceDate = dr.DateValue
left join Payments p
  on p.PaymentDate = dr.DateValue
group by dr.DateValue
order by dr.DateValue;
```

Just executing the joins would give you the result below. Because of the combined `left join` the payment row is listed twice!

```
dr.DateValue | i.Total | p.Total
------------ | ------- | -------
2020-11-01   |      20 |       5
2020-11-01   |       4 |       5 --> payment row got joined TWICE
```

Summing up those rows gives an invalid payment sum for that day.

```
group by dr.DateValue | sum(i.Total) | sum(p.Total)
--------------------- | ------------ | ------------
2020-11-01            |           24 |           10 --> last sum is WRONG !
```

---

**Edit**: SQL Server 2005 version with `cross apply`. But a SQL Server version update is still recommended!

```
with DateRange as
(
  select convert(date, '2020-11-01') as DateValue
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, dr.DateValue)
  from DateRange dr
  where dr.DateValue < '2020-11-30'
),
InvoicedTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(i.Total), 0) as Invoiced
  from DateRange dr
  left join Invoices i
    on i.InvoiceDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
),
PaidTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(p.Total), 0) as Paid
  from DateRange dr
  left join Payments p
    on p.PaymentDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
)
select convert(varchar(10), dr.DateValue, 102) as [YYYY.MM.DD],
       it1.Invoiced as [Invoiced],
       it3.Invoiced as [CumInvoiced],
       pt1.Paid as [Paid],
       pt3.Paid as [CumPaid],
       it3.Invoiced - pt3.Paid as [RunningTotal]
from DateRange dr
join InvoicedTotal it1
  on it1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
join PaidTotal pt1
  on pt1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
cross apply ( select sum(it2.Invoiced) as Invoiced
              from InvoicedTotal it2
              where it2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) it3
cross apply ( select sum(pt2.Paid) as Paid
              from PaidTotal pt2
              where pt2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) pt3
order by dr.DateValue;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a50ce6f46be8b00a41c9686ec35751f3).

Comment: Thank you, Sander, for your solution and explanation! I tried adding the script of the tables and sample data but I couldn't publish because it was too much code and stackoverflow wouldn't allow it. The problem is that I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I get an error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near 'rows'.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to migrate to a superior version of SQL Server.

Comment: I lost track of the SQL Server 2005 requirement somewhere... Answer updated with version that should work in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Works great. Thanks! Is there any way I can add a initial value to the RunningTotal?

Comment: Yes, either define a new variable for the fixed base amount and add it to the RunningTotal calculation [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae08f4bff7f7a2a0d784a52c77d6d908&hide=20) or add a new CTE and join for a variable, calculated base amount.

Comment: If I add in the Payments table a new column (InvoiceID) which will link that payment to a specific invoice, is there a way to show in the report only the payments for the issued invoices in the timeframe specified?

Comment: I think it is time for a _new question_ by now :-) Please create a _new question_ with the latest table layout, the version of the query you are using now, the current result and the expected result.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216405/running-total-for-payments-to-the-issued-invoices