# Running total for payments to the issued invoices

Tags: sql-server-2005, cumulative-sum

I have the following tables:

```
create table Invoices (InvoiceID int, InvoiceDate date, Total money);
insert into Invoices (InvoiceID, InvoiceDate, Total) values
(1,'2020-11-01', 20),
(2,'2020-11-01', 14),
(3,'2020-11-02', 40),
(4,'2020-11-02', 35),
(5,'2020-11-03', 10),
(6,'2020-11-04', 63),
(7,'2020-11-04', 42);
   
create table Payments (InvoiceID int, PaymentDate date, Total money);
insert into Payments (InvoiceID, PaymentDate, Total) values
(5,'2020-11-07', 10),
(6,'2020-11-08', 63),
(4,'2020-11-09', 35),
(2,'2020-11-10', 14),
(7,'2020-11-11', 42),
(11,'2020-11-13', 20),
(13,'2020-11-14', 15);
```

To obtain a running total using SQL Server 2005, I'm using the following script:

```
with DateRange as
(
  select convert(date, '2020-11-01') as DateValue
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, dr.DateValue)
  from DateRange dr
  where dr.DateValue < '2020-11-30'
),
InvoicedTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(i.Total), 0) as Invoiced
  from DateRange dr
  left join Invoices i
    on i.InvoiceDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
),
PaidTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(p.Total), 0) as Paid
  from DateRange dr
  left join Payments p
    on p.PaymentDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
)
select convert(varchar(10), dr.DateValue, 102) as [YYYY.MM.DD],
       it1.Invoiced as [Invoiced],
       it3.Invoiced as [CumInvoiced],
       pt1.Paid as [Paid],
       pt3.Paid as [CumPaid],
       it3.Invoiced - pt3.Paid as [RunningTotal]
from DateRange dr
join InvoicedTotal it1
  on it1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
join PaidTotal pt1
  on pt1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
cross apply ( select sum(it2.Invoiced) as Invoiced
              from InvoicedTotal it2
              where it2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) it3
cross apply ( select sum(pt2.Paid) as Paid
              from PaidTotal pt2
              where pt2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) pt3
order by dr.DateValue;
```

How to show in the report only the payments for the issued invoices in the timeframe specified?

Comment: The specified time frame here is `2020-11-01` to `2020-11-30`? All the sample data is for November, 2020. So all sample data will be included. New sample data for, say, December will not be part of the calculations as long as the `DateRange` CTE is not updated. Could you please update the sample data (if needed) and provide the target time frame and the corresponding expected result?

Comment: I've modified the fiddle, see here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc1b80ea16ec372a3a5d033eb2d8a61f

Comment: As you can see from the data in Payments table, for the last two records (InvoiceID: 11 and 13) there isn't any record in Invoices table, so I want those two to be excluded from the report calculated values.

Comment: Think I got it. I updated your question with the info from the fiddle website. StackOverflow  questions should not depend on question data that is only available on external sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with DateRange as
(
  select convert(date, '2020-11-01') as DateValue
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, dr.DateValue)
  from DateRange dr
  where dr.DateValue < '2020-11-30'
),
InvoicedTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(i.Total), 0) as Invoiced
  from DateRange dr
  left join Invoices i
    on i.InvoiceDate = dr.DateValue
  group by dr.DateValue
),
PaidTotal as
(
  select dr.DateValue,
         isnull(sum(case
                      when i.InvoiceDate between '2020-11-01' and '2020-11-30' -- check if matching invoice was found
                      then p.Total                 -- YES = include Total amount in sum
                      else 0                       -- NO  = exclude total amount from sum
                    end), 0) as Paid
  from DateRange dr
  left join Payments p
    on p.PaymentDate = dr.DateValue
  left join Invoices i
    on  i.InvoiceId = p.InvoiceId -- check for invoice related to payment
  group by dr.DateValue
)
select convert(varchar(10), dr.DateValue, 102) as [YYYY.MM.DD],
       it1.Invoiced as [Invoiced],
       it3.Invoiced as [CumInvoiced],
       pt1.Paid as [Paid],
       pt3.Paid as [CumPaid],
       it3.Invoiced - pt3.Paid as [RunningTotal]
from DateRange dr
join InvoicedTotal it1
  on it1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
join PaidTotal pt1
  on pt1.DateValue = dr.DateValue
cross apply ( select sum(it2.Invoiced) as Invoiced
              from InvoicedTotal it2
              where it2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) it3
cross apply ( select sum(pt2.Paid) as Paid
              from PaidTotal pt2
              where pt2.DateValue <= dr.DateValue ) pt3
order by dr.DateValue;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2bf6305c77f61c414bc2b71282074940) by [milo2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538820/milo2011)

Comment: No, the values are still selected in the report. I've modified the fiddler so that it inserts the invoices from outside report interval. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e685aca6446796fd85782c1ebf336bfb

Comment: See this screenshot with the problem values that should not be there: https://prnt.sc/vz4sqk

Comment: I think I figured it out. Where you were checking if matching invoice was found, I replaced it with a BETWEEN operator. See:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2bf6305c77f61c414bc2b71282074940

Comment: Glad you got it working for you! I have updated the answer to match your solution and made it "community wiki". With enough reputation you should be able to update it yourself for future reference in case of changes.